# `ngFor` creates more items

Tags: angular, dom, ngfor

I use Angular 10 and the `*ngFor` directive to create a list of elements. Whenever the input array changes, I do something with the element. E.g:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.elements.changes.subscribe(t => {
    this.loadElementInfos();
  })
}
```

If I set a `break-point` inside the function, occasionally I see that `*ngFor` actually adds the new elements to the list, and then discards the old elements.

**e.g**:

```sh
old-element-0
old-element-1
old-element-2
old-element-3
new-element-0
new-element-1
new-element-2
new-element-3
```

And a millisecond later the old elements are discarded. Is there any chance to control that behavior of `ngFor` to not do that?

```sh
new-element-0
new-element-1
new-element-2
new-element-3
```

Comment: really depends what you're doing in that function and what the objects look like, but generally you can control this with the `trackBy` clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If we need at some point to change the data in the collection, Angular needs to remove all the `DOM` elements that associated with
> the data and create them again. That means a lot of `DOM`
> manipulations especially in a case of a big collection, and as we
> know, `DOM` manipulations are expensive.

You can help Angular to track which items added or removed by providing a `trackBy` function like this:

**app.component.ts**

```js
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `./my-app.html`,
})
export class App {
  collection = any[];
  constructor() {
    this.collection = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
  }

  trackByFn(index, item) {
    return index;
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<ul>
 <li *ngFor="let item of collection;trackBy: trackByFn">{{item.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

For more understanding see this helpful Article: **[Improve Performance with trackBy](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5)**